# Error using convert MySQL in Python

Tags: mysql, python

I'm practically newbie with MySQL.
I'm trying to do a query to retrieve a preformatted date, obtained from a subtraction, using `CONVERT`. 

This is the query:

```
sql = f"SELECT CONVERT(timestamp - {sqlToday}, getdate(), 23), count_issue FROM total_unresolved_issue WHERE project = '{project}'"
```

`timestamp` is a column of the database, and `sqlToday` is a date in format `datetime.date(2020, 2, 13)`. 
Unfortunately this error returns, and I don't know how to handle it:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'getdate(),
>   23), count_issue FROM total_unresolved_issue WHERE project = 'Graphic'
>   at line 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) syntax you have here isn't mysql. What do you want this expression to return? [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is the current date (and other date functions in the link).

Comment: I have tried `NOW()`. It works very well, thanks @danblack! I found the convert documentation [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/). But at this point I believe it is totally incomplete.

Comment: your link is for SQL-Server. Quite different product. Some SQL is the same, some different. There's enough MySQL documentation to keep you from guessing what is/isn't correct. The good thing about MySQL/MariaDB errors is they point exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Really? And where is this documentation available?

Comment: previous links, and just noticed [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/built-in-functions/) in the error so linked its documentation too. Keep asking if you get stuck however.

Comment: The error is pointing to "getdate"; look that up.  When you don't find it, search for "MySQL date functions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it is not easy to find the right command we need for queries in the MySQL documentation. 
However, by testing, I saw that this should be fine:

```
sql = f"SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp), count_issue FROM total_unresolved_issue WHERE project = '{project}'"
```

`DATEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp)` returns the difference between two dates in days.